# !!RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars

Tags: python, opencv

My purpose in this code is to measure the distance of a black object in an image obtained using the camera, but as mentioned in the error below, this event does not occur.
The code is as follows:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

def make_coordinates(image, line_parameters):
    slope, intercept = line_parameters
    y1 = image.shape[0]
    y2 = int(y1*(3/5))
    x1 = int((y1 - intercept)/slope)
    x2 = int((y2 - intercept)/slope)
    return np.array([x1, y1, x2, y2])
def average_slope_intercept(image, lines):
    left_fit = []
    right_fit = []
    if lines is not None:
        for line in lines:
            x1, y1, x2, y2 = line.reshape(4)
            parameters = np.polyfit((x1, x2), (y1, y2), 1)
            slope = parameters[0]
            intercept = parameters[1]
            if slope < 0:
                left_fit.append((slope, intercept))
            else:
                right_fit.append((slope, intercept))
        left_fit_average = np.average(left_fit, axis=0)
        #right_fit_average = np.average(right_fit, axis=0)
        print(left_fit_average, 'left')
        #print(right_fit_average, 'right')
        left_line = make_coordinates(image, left_fit_average)
        #right_line = make_coordinates(image, right_fit_average)
        return np.array([left_line])


def distance_to_camera(knownWidth, focalLength, perWidth):
    return (knownWidth * focalLength) / perWidth
# The first step in finding the distance from the object or mark in the image is to calibrate and calculate the focal length . So , We need to know ：
# Initialize the distance from a known object to the camera
KNOWN_DISTANCE = 24.0
# Initializes the width of a known object
KNOWN_WIDTH = 11.0

def canny(img):
    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_RBG2HSV)
    black_lower = np.array([0, 0, 0])
    black_upper = np.array([180, 255, 30])
    black_mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, black_lower, black_upper)
    kernel = 5
    blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(black_mask, (kernel, kernel),0)
    canny = cv2.Canny(blur, 50, 150)
    return canny

def display_lines(img, lines):
    line_image = np.zeros_like(img)
    if lines is not None:
        for line in lines:
            for x1, y1, x2, y2 in line:
                cv2.line(line_image, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (255, 0, 0), 10)
    return line_image


def region_of_interest(canny):
    height = canny.shape[0]
    width = canny.shape[1]
    mask = np.zeros_like(canny)

    square = np.array([[(635,478),(0,478),(281,200)]
                       ])
    cv2.fillPoly(mask, square, 255)
    masked_image = cv2.bitwise_and(canny, mask)
    return masked_image

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
_,c_image = cap.read()
marker = canny(c_image)
focalLength = (marker [1][0] * KNOWN_DISTANCE) / KNOWN_WIDTH
print('focalLength', focalLength)
while True:
    _, frame = cap.read()
    canny_image = canny(frame)
    cropped_canny = region_of_interest(canny_image)
    lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(cropped_canny, 2, np.pi / 180, 100, np.array([]), minLineLength=40, maxLineGap=5)
    averaged_lines = average_slope_intercept(frame, lines)
    line_image = display_lines(frame, averaged_lines)
    combo_image = cv2.addWeighted(frame, 0.8, line_image, 1, 1)
    CM = distance_to_camera(KNOWN_WIDTH, focalLength, marker[1][0])
    cv2.imshow("result", combo_image)
    cv2.putText(frame, "%.2fft" % CM,
                (frame.shape[1] - 200, frame.shape[0] - 20), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,
                2.0, (0, 255, 0), 3)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

The resulting image as a result of the written code

[image]

The error is as follows.

```
>>> %Run mesafe.py
focalLength 0.0
[-3.89346104e-01  4.41339935e+02] left
mesafe.py:18: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars
  return (knownWidth * focalLength) / perWidth
[-3.90163497e-01  4.41415626e+02] left
[-3.85150497e-01  4.40625233e+02] left
[-3.93702170e-01  4.43145302e+02] left
```

Comment: try printing `knownWidth`,  `focalLength` and `perWidth` and check if they are valid

Comment: focalLength and perWidth show 0. How can I fix this?

Comment: you know your code. you know where the values come from. use a debugger (pdb, python's debugger).

Comment: if `perWidth` is 0, you are dividing by 0, this is **the** problem

Comment: you created a funtcino `canny` that usese the `Canny` function of opencv and has a `canny` variable, try cleaning this and you may find the root of all your problems :)

Comment: Nothing changed, I couldn't find the problem.